# Increase the line width when hovering the cursor in plotly?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'd like to increase the width of the line and its points when hovering the mouse cursor over a line. Animate parameters such as marker size and line width somehow when the mouse cursor is over them. How can I do that?

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.24.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <script>
    var data = [
      {
        x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
        y: [1, 3, 6],
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: "lines+markers",
        marker: {
          size: 10
        },
        line: {
          width: 4
        }
      }
    ];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried asking your question on the Plotly community forum? https://community.plotly.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [plotly_hover](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#hover-event) event is only triggered on hovering the markers (datapoints):

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.24.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <script>
var data = [
  {
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 3, 6],
    type: 'scatter',
    mode: "lines+markers",
    marker: {
      size: 10
    },
    line: {
      width: 4
    }
  }
];
var layout = {
title: 'plotly_hover',
autorange: false,
  xaxis: {
    range: ['2013-10-04 00:00:00', '2013-12-06 00:00:00']
  },
  yaxis: {
    range: [0, 7]
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv')
myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(){
  var update = {'line.width': 10, 'marker.size': 20};
  Plotly.restyle(myPlot, update, 0);
});
myPlot.on('plotly_unhover', function(){
  var update = {'line.width': 4, 'marker.size': 10};
  Plotly.restyle(myPlot, update, 0);
});
  </script>
</body>
```

Please also check plotly's function reference on [Plotly.restyle](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle).

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that the scale of the rest of the chart changes slightly when hovering the mouse over the line. Can this be fixed?

Comment: For some reason it gives an error after several hovering attempts `{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}`

Comment: To avoid resizing the axes via `autorange` you can provide a fixed `range`, please see my edit. I can't reproduce the error you are mentioning.